# How to find parts of xml data to import into Excel, based on column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

For work I am creating machine files which data needs to be manually put in ERP.
To automate this process I made Excel sheets to be able to import the data.
The CAM program generates an .fmx file (xml) where all the relevant data can be found. I just need to import 3 items in 3 different columns in Excel, so I made a schema file. On import this works nice for one file, but thats it.
Because I can't create the code myself, I would like to ask if someone could help to create this code.
Based on values in column A5 to end, the .fmx files should be found inside a folder with the same values. according to the schema file the correct data should be extracted to 3 different columns.

[image]

Comment: Though this is not an answer, it's a good workaround. Try converting your XML to CSV http://xmlgrid.net/xml2text.html. You can open CSV files in excel and save the data that u want

Comment: XML data is essentially free-form hierarchical data. Excel only deals with tables. While some XML files can be interpreted as tables, this one cannot. // If you’re not a programmer, you *should* not even attempt to solve this problem. Whatever you come up with will later stop working and probably be passed to an external software company. Do yourself and your company a favor and strongly recommend your superior to get external help *right now*.

Comment: I know (for a long time) your answer is the only correct one, so until (and if) we get that external help I guess I will have to import the xml data by hand one by one.